# IONIC v3 PopoverController se sale del área visible

Tags: ionic

Os comento, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Tengo una aplicación en IONIC v3, la idea es que la visualización en el explorador web no sea a "pantalla completa", puesto que esta dispuesta para verse en un terminal Android y queremos que la apariencia sea igual.

Por ello, he probado establecer en el app.css lo siguiente :

```
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .app-root {
    width: 620px;
    min-width: 620px;
    max-width: 620px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;      
  }

  .scroll-content {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
  }
}
```

Con ello he conseguido el resultado esperado :

[image: Imagen 1]

Pero cuando pulso sobre el "ojo"para que me aparezca un menú desplegable, el cual he usado "PopoverController", no me aparece correctamente :

[image: Imagen 2]

Tanto el .ts como el .html es algo tan sencillo como esto :

```
<button ion-button icon-only  (click)="vistas($event)">
   <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

y el .ts :

```
  vistas(myEvent) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MenuarticulosPage', {homeRef: this},{});
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
    popover.onWillDismiss(() => {
    });
  }
```

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Bienvenido cagavantes!!!...  Por una cuestión de disposición de los elementos en pantalla, por que no usas las grid para hacer esos espacios verticales? Te ayudará inclusive en tu error de visualización... Te dejo este enlace para mayor información:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/grid/Grid/